# Position text under responsive div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm looking for help to position text directly underneath responsive divs(images).

Divs in question jump up and down the page to adjust to the viewport nicely, but I can't figure out how to fix the text which is supposed to be always centered underneath each image.

Text-align: center; works nicely on max view-port but once the boxes are responding to the smaller window the text doesn't quite follow them in the center, it sort of scooches to the side.

Any suggestions appreciated, not sure how well my code snippet will work...

```css
.flexgrid {
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center; 
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexgrid > li { 
    width: 20%; 
    list-style-type: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1337px) {
  .flexgrid > li { 
        width: 25%;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1072) {
  .flexgrid > li { 
        width: 35%;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="flexgrid">

    <li><div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" alt="" style="display: block; height: 250px; width: 250px; margin: 5px;"></div>Coal</li>
    <li><div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" alt="" style="display: block; height: 250px; width: 250px; margin: 5px;"></div>Dry Wood</li>
    <li><div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" alt="" style="display: block; height: 250px; width: 250px; margin: 5px;"></div>Something else</li>
    <li><div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" alt="" style="display: block; height: 250px; width: 250px; margin: 5px;"></div>Something else</li>
    <li><div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" alt="" style="display: block; height: 250px; width: 250px; margin: 5px;"></div>Something else</li>
    
</ul>
```

Comment: Try margin 0 auto; display :block //centers that tag when applied on a tag

Comment: insert the text inside a tag, like a `div`, give this tag a class. give this class a css with text-align center and width 100%.
Also, if you force your images to 250px, modifying the `li` to 25% or 35% of width won't change the image size, it will overflow over the other images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `figure` and `figcaption` tags (i.e. the usual way to put text under an image and handle them as a unit) which can be styled as desired - see below. Also borders for image *and* text together, background etc. would be possible that way.

```css
.flexgrid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexgrid>li {
  width: 20%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

figure {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1337px) {
  .flexgrid>li {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1072) {
  .flexgrid>li {
    width: 35%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="flexgrid">

  <li>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
      <figure><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" alt=""
        <figcaption>Coal</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
      <figure><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" alt=""
        <figcaption>Dry Wood</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
      <figure><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" alt=""
        <figcaption>Something else</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
      <figure><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" alt="">
        <figcaption>Something else</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
      <figure><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" alt="">
        <figcaption>Something else</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I'd also suggest switching out the unordered list (ul) for a section element and all of the list items (li) and then clear up the CSS.

Comment: @MichaelGearon I just used the code from the question and added/changed whatever is necessary to achieve what the OP asked for.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. It was just a suggestion on how it could be improved further